# How do I return a WeightedChoice from a function?

Tags: rust

I'd like to make a function that takes a parameter `x: uint` returns a [`WeightedChoice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/distributions/struct.WeightedChoice.html) with options `'a'` and `'b'` of weights `x` and `1u`, respectively. How can I do that?

This is obviously wrong, but just to give an idea of what I'm trying for:

```
use std::rand::distributions::{WeightedChoice, Weighted};
fn make_wc<'a>(x: uint) -> WeightedChoice<'a, char> {
    let mut items = [Weighted { weight: x, item: 'a' },
                     Weighted { weight: 1, item: 'b' }];
    WeightedChoice::new(???)
}
```

The part that's confusing me is the lifetime parameter. As far as I know, I can't create anything of lifetime `'a` inside the function, but the argument of `WeightedChoice::new` needs to have type `&'a mut [Weighted<char>]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right, it is impossible to create anything of lifetime specified as a parameter to a function.

It is possible to return `WeightedChoice<'static, char>` but it would require using `&'static mut [Weighted<T>]` which is not appropriate for your use case (if possible at all).

What you can do is "encapsulate" `WeightedChoice` data into your own struct which would have methods for generating `WeightedChoice`:

```
use std::rand::distributions::{Weighted, WeightedChoice};

struct OwningWc<T> {
    items: Vec<Weighted<T>>
}

impl<T: Clone> OwningWc<T> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new(items: Vec<Weighted<T>>) -> OwningWc<T> {
        OwningWc { items: items }
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn get(&mut self) -> WeightedChoice<T> {
        WeightedChoice::new(self.items[mut])
    }
}
```

And then you would use it like this:

```
fn make_wc(x: uint) -> OwningWc<char> {
    let items = vec![Weighted { weight: x, item: 'a' },
                     Weighted { weight: 1, item: 'b' }];
    OwningWc::new(items)
}

let owc = make_wc(10);
let wc: WeightedChoice<char> = owc.get();
```

If you don't need genericity, you can optimize `OwningWc` struct to have, say, `[Weighted<char>, ..2]` field instead of `Vec<Weighted<T>>`. You won't even need dynamic allocation in this case.