# Storing a WeightedChoice in a struct

Tags: rust

I apologize in advance for the code dump. I trimmed it down as much as I
could without losing the context of my question (in **bold** below).

I have a struct

```
use std::rand;
use std::rand::Rng;
use std::rand::distributions::{Weighted, WeightedChoice, Sample, IndependentSample};

struct MarkovChain {
    state: uint,
    weights: Vec<Vec<uint>>,
}
```

modeling a Markov chain. There are some checks on the dimensions of the
`weights` matrix that I implement in `MarkovChain::new`:

```
impl MarkovChain {
    fn new(weights: Vec<Vec<uint>>, initial_state: uint) -> MarkovChain {
        let states = weights.len();
        assert!(states > 0);
        assert!(initial_state < states);
        assert!(weights.iter().all(|row| row.len() == states));
        MarkovChain {
            state: initial_state,
            weights: weights,
        }
    }
}
```

Now I implement [`Sample`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/rand/distributions/trait.Sample.html):

```
impl Sample<uint> for MarkovChain {
    fn sample<R: Rng>(&mut self, rng: &mut R) -> uint {
        // I'd like to put the following part in MarkovChain::new
        // instead, but I can't figure out how to store the
        // WeightedChoice inside the MarkovChain struct.
        //BEGIN
        let mut row = self.weights[self.state]
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .map(|(i, &wt)| Weighted { item: i, weight: wt })
            .collect::<Vec<Weighted<uint>>>();
        let wc = WeightedChoice::new(row.as_mut_slice());
        //END

        self.state = wc.ind_sample(rng);
        self.state
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `row` and `wc` need to be constructed every
time `sample` is called. Given that the typical use case involves
calling `sample` many, many times, this is a problem.

**I'd like to move the calculation of `row` and `wc` (for each state)
into `MarkovChain::new` instead, but I can't seem to figure out how to
store a [`WeightedChoice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rand/distributions/struct.WeightedChoice.html) in the `MarkovChain` struct. How do I do that?**

I can't tell if this is actually difficult, or if I'm suffering brain damage from too many years of garbage collected languages.

---

Here's an example usage of the Markov chain. I want to keep the interface unchanged, if possible:

```
fn main() {
    // Create the 3-state Markov chain illustrated at
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Markov_chain&oldid=626307401#Example
    let mut mc = MarkovChain::new(vec![vec![900,  75,  25],
                                       vec![150, 800,  50],
                                       vec![250, 250, 500]], 0);

    // Expect around 62.5% 0s, 31.25% 1s, and 6.25% 2s after many iterations.
    let rng = &mut rand::task_rng();
    let mut stats = vec![0u, 0, 0];
    for _ in range(0u, 10000) {
        *stats.get_mut(mc.sample(rng)) += 1;
    }
    println!("Expect approximately [6250, 3125, 625]:");
    println!("{}", stats);
}
```

Here's the whole thing in the [Rust playpen](http://is.gd/abWi2o).

Comment: For anyone experiencing déjà vu, this question is distinct from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26230437/how-do-i-return-a-weightedchoice-from-a-function), which was about *returning* a WeightedChoice.

Comment: You can pretty easily compute your `row`s in `new()`, but I don't see how you can do the same for the `WeightedChoice`s. The issue is that you have no way to prove to the compiler that the reference it borrows is safely owned by your `MarkovChain` struct...

Comment: Unfortunately, even moving the just the `row`s into `new()` is tricky: `WeightedChoice::new(&'a mut [Weighted<T>])` modifies its argument, so creating multiple `wc`s for the same `row` skews the probability distribution.

Comment: See this related question: [How to initialize struct fields which reference each other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25269597/234590)